# How to find a string and remove it from the string?

Tags: c#

here I want to remove some part of a string from the the string.
 my main string is like `<grade xsi:nil="true" /><hollanderGroup xsi:nil="true" /><interchangeNumber xsi:nil="true" /><interchangeDetails xsi:nil="true" /><damageCodes xsi:nil="true" /><damageCode1 xsi:nil="true" /><damageCode2 xsi:nil="true" />` from which I want to replace this part `<grade xsi:nil="true" />` for which I am trying the below code

```
string str="<grade xsi:nil=''true'' />";
string  MainString="<grade xsi:nil=''true'' /><hollanderGroup xsi:nil=''true'' /><interchangeNumber xsi:nil=''true'' /><interchangeDetails xsi:nil=''true'' /><damageCodes xsi:nil=''true'' /><damageCode1 xsi:nil=''true'' /><damageCode2 xsi:nil=''true'' />"
```

for this I tried something like.

```
string resultatntString = MainString.Replace(str, " ");
```

but I can't see the change in my Original string the part is not getting removed/replaced by empty space..
so is there any solution for this?

Comment: Is this how your real code is? With the `'` around the strings?

Comment: "This thing is not working" is not a question, nor is it descriptive of a problem. You know what the error, bad result, expected result, etc. (relevant information) is. If you want people to help you, please share this information in future. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Thanks John,
I posted this because it is not working and still it is not working.

Comment: @Ma6139735 - John is asking for a better description of the problem other than "this thing is not working". Writing "still it is not working" isn't a better description. Please explain what's not working.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine if you replace `'` with `"`, as per our syntax we must enclose a string inside a pair of `"`(double quotes) and character inside a single quotes:

```
string str="remove the sub-string";
string  MainString="This is the main string and I want to remove the sub-string";
string resultantString = MainString.Replace(str, " ");
Console.WriteLine(resultantString);
// will print "This is the main string and I want to" in the console
```

One more thing, need not to use `var` everywhere in the declaration, use proper types if you are aware about the type of data at the time of writing the code

Alternatively you can use different methods like, Substring, Remove as well. Here I have added a [working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W0m6Kk) that shows various methods to achieve the same

Comment: I have Updated my question please have a look over it

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine. Make sure you are declaring str as string.

in `C#`, `'s'` is a character whereas `"S"` is a string.

```
using System;
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    string custString = "Hello World";
    string change = "World";
    Console.WriteLine(custString.Replace(change,"Me"));
  }
}
```

[Link to Repl.it working code](https://repl.it/KTlx/1)

Answer (score -2):

Try with StringBuilder Object, it works.

```
var str = "remove the sub-string";
var mainString = new StringBuilder("This is the main string and I want to remove the sub-string");
mainString.Replace(str, " ");
```

Comment: How does this explain the issue in the OP's question?